# Volume of open rectangular box w/o a square bottom

Tags: derivatives, optimization, partial-derivative

I am attempting to solve the following question:

> An open rectangular box having a volume of 108 $\text{cm}^3$ is to be constructed from metal sheets. Find the dimensions of such a box if the amount of metal used in its construction is to be minimised.

We assume that the cost of the metal varies proportionately with the amount. Let $L$, $W$, and $H$ be the length, width, and height respectively. Let $C$ be the total cost. Since the cost varies proportionately, then $C = L + W + H$. The aim is therefore to minimise $C$.

Since $L \times W \times H = 108 \Rightarrow H = \dfrac{108}{W \times L}$.

Substituting $H$ into $C$, we obtain the equation: $C = L + W + \dfrac{108}{LW}$.

To minimise $C$, we use partial derivatives as follows:

- $\dfrac{\partial{C}}{\partial{L}} = 1 - \dfrac{108}{WL^2}$ and $\dfrac{\partial^{2}{C}}{\partial^2{L}} = \dfrac{216}{WL^3}$
- $\dfrac{\partial{C}}{\partial{L}} = 1 - \dfrac{108}{L^2W}$ and $\dfrac{\partial^{2}{C}}{\partial^2{L}} = \dfrac{216}{W^3L}$
- $\dfrac{\partial^{2}{C}}{\partial{L}\partial{W}} = \dfrac{\partial^{2}{C}}{\partial{W}\partial{L}} = \dfrac{108}{L^2 W^2}$

From $C_L = 0$, we obtain $W = \dfrac{108}{L^2}$ (*) and substituting this result into the equation $C_W = 0$, we obtain $L = \pm \sqrt{108}$. We reject $L < 0$ because the length cannot be negative.

Substituting $L = \sqrt{108}$ into (*) we obtain $W = 1$ and then substituting into $H$ we obtain $H = 1$.

Notwithstanding the proof of whether the dimensions would give the minimum, I am quite suspicious of the result of $H = 1$, $W = 1$ and $L = 108$.

Is an optimised solution even possible for this question?

Comment: You need to consier the **surfaces** to get the cost.

Comment: That is my mistake. Thanks. But after finding the surface, is partial derivatives the correct method to find the minimum solution?

Comment: Fix the expression of $C$ first and we shall see ! Cheers.

Comment: Violà! The answer is $L = \sqrt[3]{108}$ and $W = 108^{2/3}$, $H = 1$ follows from there? Cheers.

Comment: I do repeat : what is $C$ ?

Comment: $C = 2(LW + WH + LH)$

Comment: This is not for an open box. Not too far ...